# Disabling Add Item and Delete Item from a View without changing permissions

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

I have a Data View created in sharepoint designer that enables users to edit data, but also has access to add/delete items which i want to disable. 
Is there any chance to do this without changing user permissions?
Thanks
Nuno

Comment: You can add Script editor web part to the page and add js code which will disable or hide buttons.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do it without changing rights, but why not create a custom permissions set that enables only to edit, not add or delete - and then give the user group that permission level for your desired specific list or library?

See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels-53c86040-07fa-4ea7-bc55-34ee96b437fe

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to do that without changing user permissions on the library.

As a workaround, there is a GitHub solution which allows to specify the permission for Users, SharePoint Groups or Active Directory Groups which will not have the permission to get to some Views. You can try to use [it](https://github.com/pasmik/sp2013columnpermission).